# Can I set a PBI alert on something other than a card, guage or kpi?

Tags: powerbi, alerts

I need to set an alert based on the report below, showing counts of passengers per flight. I need the alert to be triggered if the passenger count per flight is >= 15. From my understanding I alerts can only be set from KPI's, Gauges or Cards. I am stuck on how to create a card that can show this information, as date and flight number are needed in order to know how many passengers are on that flight. I am guessing a measure can be made to take into account both of these attributes, but I am stuck on how to go about this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It definitely seems like this is still a PBI limitation, however I set up daily subscriptions with a link to a filtered version of this report based on the passenger per flight count of >=15. Not the best solution, but works for now.